# Can't pass BluetoothAdapter object via putExtra method of Intent

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am trying to pass my `BluetoothAdapter BA` to another activity using `putExtra(String str, Bundle bundle)` method of Intent, but the compiler of my Android studio shows an error in that. When I hover over a red curved line that appears under the method, it shows me

```
Can't resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter)'
```

[image] 
This is what I'm talking about

If I understand it correctly, Bundle is basically any object, hence there shouldn't be any problem passing a BluetoothAdapter to another activity via putExtra.

This is my **MainActivity.java**

```
package vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public BluetoothAdapter BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    private int REQ_CODE = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void connect(View v)
    {
        if(BA == null)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "System Doesn't Support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        else if(!BA.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBT, REQ_CODE);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ALREADY ON!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            searchBTDevices();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode!=RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TURNED ON!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            searchBTDevices();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"FAILED TO ENABLE BLUETOOTH", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }




    public void searchBTDevices()
    {
        Thread searchThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent searchBT = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchBTDevice.class);
                searchBT.putExtra("BT_ADAPTER", BA);
                startActivity(searchBT);
            }
        };
        searchThread.start();
    }
}
```

And this is my **SearchBTDevices.java** that is supposed to receive the extra info.

```
package vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class SearchBTDevice extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_btdevice);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: BluetoothAdapter is not a Parcelable or any other object that can fit in a Bundle so you can't do this ever. You have to get the Adapter back in the Activity that the intent opens.

Comment: And how do I do that? I'm new to Android

Comment: `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` is a static method so it can be called anywhere. If `SearchBTDevices` needs a bluetooth adapter, then it can just call this to retrieve it.

Comment: What if I have two Bluetooth Adapters in my app like `BluetoothAdapter BA , BLAdapter`, which adapter would `getDefaultAdapter` return? And how would the intent now which one to retrieve?

Comment: And I don't want just another BluetoothAdapter in my `SearchBTDevices.java`, I need the one used in `MainActivity.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Intents can only be used to pass primitives, `Parcelable` and `Serializable` objects. `BluetoothAdapter` does not support either of these and it can't be built from primitives, so you can't create a Parcelable that will help you.

So when faced with a situation like this, you need to pass in parameters that the Activty can use to re-build or retrieve the object necessary for execution.

If you need the ability to use different BluetoothAdapters, then you need to tell `SearchBTDevices` which BluetoothAdapter you want to check and have `SearchBTDevices` retrieve the adapter itself.  For example,

```
public class SearchBTDevices extends Activity {
   public static final String PARAM_ADAPTER_TYPE = "adapterType";
   public static final int ADAPTER_DEFAULT = 1;
   public static final int ADAPTER_ALTERNATE = 2;

   private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      int adapterType = getIntent().getIntExtra(PARAM_ADAPTER_TYPE, ADAPTER_DEFAULT);
      switch(adapterType) {
         case PARAM_ADAPTER_ALTERNATE:
             mAdapter = getAlternateAdapter(); // This is whatever method you need to get it.
             break;
         default:
             mAdapter = getDefaultAdapter();
      }
   }
}
```

Now, whenever you need to start this Activity, just do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SearchBTDevices.class);
intent.putExtra(SearchBTDevices.PARAM_ADAPTER_TYPE, SearchBTDevices.ADAPTER_ALTERNATE);
startActivity(intent);
```

So when `SearchBTDevices` starts, it will pull the parameter from the intent and know that it needs to use the alternate adapter.